# Count number of login parse swift

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I want to count number of login for a specific user, I know it easy like question but, If someone can guide me a little bit, I'm pretty new in swift :)

```js
let nbConexion = PFUser.currentUser()!.objectForKey("nbconnexion") as? Int
if x = B{
(nbConexion)! + 1}
```

but seems doesn't work 
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a class in Parse called "Session". It automatically records every logins on an app or just simply opening the app.

It has a "user" property. So you just basically query the sessions where the user was your current user and print the array count :)

Hope it helps!

```
var query = PFQuery(className: "_Session")
query.whereKey("user", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser())
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects , error ) -> Void in
    if error == nil{
        print((objects as! [PFObject]).count)
    }
}
```

Comment: @sahanthegreat I want count it in a specific moment when the customer taped in a specific button, I want add this count, can someone help me with that :)

Comment: ok, add a field to your "_User" class. then when a user did an action, (not just login, any action) increment that particular field with this method: user.incrementKey("votes", byAmount: 1)